# PS2 keyboard in OpenBSD 6.4

Tags: keyboard, openbsd

On OpenBSD 6.4 , my usb keyboard is dead so i get a old ps2 keyboard.
The problem now is that it is configured as qwerty keyboard and it is a azerty keyboard.
I can set it in xfce with :

```
  Keyboard model : Logitech internet 350 keyboard
  Keyboard layout : French (Azerty)
```

It is always qwerty in xenodm.
dmesg tell me :

```
pckbc0 at isa0 port 0x60/5 irq 1 irq 12
pckbd0 at pckbc0 (kbd slot)
wskbd0 at pckbd0: console keyboard, using wsdisplay0
```

There is no keyboard listed with wsconsctl.
So with `wsconctl keyboard.encoding=fr`, i get :

```
wsconsctl: /dev/wskbd0: No such file or directory.
```

What can i do ?

Comment: The error message is (I believe) misleading (in 6.5 it says "Permission denied"). Try again with `doas` (i.e. as root).

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for comment, I try that at root like it's system configuration. /dev/wskbd0 don't exist. I try to use MAKEDEV script with no avail. One more think ?

Comment: Hmm... That's a device file that _should_ exist. Did you run `cd /dev && doas ./MAKEDEV all`? Usually, following normal installation or upgrade procedures should have created that device.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks MAKEDEV all do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/dev/wskbd0` device should exist on an OpenBSD 6.4 system.  If it doesn't, it's a sign of a botched or incomplete upgrade or installation (creating the devices is usually the last step in an installation or upgrade and is done automatically if you install/upgrade by booting the `bsd.rd` kernel), or you may have deleted some device files manually.

To recreate the default devices, use

```
cd /dev && doas ./MAKEDEV all
```

The `/dev/MAKEDEV` script will then recreate the device files that should exist on any OpenBSD 6.4 system, including the `/dev/wskbd0` file.

Comment: I never delete /dev/wskbd0. i only change tthe keyboard. I don't understand what happen but MAKEDEV all create or recreate /dev/wskbd0 and this way, all is ok.